# Querying inside json column in laravel elequent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysql-json

i have a model called `orders` which have an `info` json column .
in that json i have a property called `id` . now i want to retrieve all orders with the id of `6` for example . so here is how i have done like below :

```
  $order = \DB::table('orders')
                ->where('info.id',$value)
               // ->where('info->id',$value)
//            ->whereRaw('JSON_EXTRACT(`info` , "$.id") = '.$value)
                ->first();
```

the third `whereRaw` is working but i think it has a bug because in my validation thirds or 4th one returns this error which is so strange :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '6112 ' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `orders` where JSON_EXTRACT(`info` , "$.id") = 6112  limit 1)
```

it some how mistakes the column value as the column name which is so strange because its working on first ones when i `dd` i get the values from query but it breakes on like 4th one  .
now i wanted to know if there is any easier solution to use where on json fields or what is the problem with that whereRaw

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Laravel supports querying JSON column types on databases that provide support for JSON column types.

Currently, this includes MySQL 5.7+, PostgreSQL, SQL Server 2016, and SQLite 3.9.0 (with the [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)).

To query a JSON column, use the `->` operator:

```
$order = DB::table('orders')
        ->where('info->id', $value)
        ->first();
```

---

Additional information from the doc : [JSON Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses)

You may use `whereJsonContains` to query JSON arrays. *This feature is not supported by the SQLite database*:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->whereJsonContains('options->languages', 'en')
    ->get();
```

If your application uses the MySQL or PostgreSQL databases, you may pass an array of values to the `whereJsonContains` method:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->whereJsonContains('options->languages', ['en', 'de'])
    ->get();
```

You may use `whereJsonLength` method to query JSON arrays by their length:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->whereJsonLength('options->languages', 0)
    ->get();
 
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->whereJsonLength('options->languages', '>', 1)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Link to documentation about this feature: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: Ah I forgot to include the link. Thank you @BillKarwin.